# RESTEasy + Spring + Jackson + Jaxb

Tags: jaxb, jackson, resteasy

I am trying to serialize JAXB annotated class with Jackson using RESTEasy. By default ResteasyJacksonProvider is configured to use JACKSON annotation only. Is there a way to configure ResteasyJacksonProvider to use JAXB annotation using spring? There are couple of programmatic ways but would prefer if there is some spring configuration.

Couple of ways I am thinking of

1. Use ContextResolver for ObjectMapper type to return ObjectMapper configured to use JaxbAnnotationIntrospector instead of JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.
2. Extend ResteasyJacksonProvider and pass JAXB annotation during construction.

Any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Well the first option of using ContextResolver works but I still think there should be an easier way to do this just by some configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this from the configuration only, no need to program anything special.
Here's how to:
First set your configuration right, I use Jackson + JAXB, both set under ContentNegotiatingViewResolver bean:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <property name="marshaller">
                        <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
                            <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.shay.dashboard.data.structure.page.PageObject" />
                            <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.shay.dashboard.data.structure.tab.TabObject" />
                            <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.shay.dashboard.data.structure.section.SectionObject" />
                            <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.shay.dashboard.data.structure.element.nonembedded.ElementObject"/>
                            <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.shay.dashboard.data.structure.element.embedded.EmbeddedElementObject"/>
                            <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.shay.dashboard.data.structure.chart.common.ChartManager"/>
                        </oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Notice that under the marshaller I set the oxm:class-to-be-bound - those are the classes to be bound by JAXB.

Now for the module, I used ordinary annotation package (javax.xml.bind.annotation), non marshaller specific. Jackson Json and JAXB both know how to read it.

For example:

`@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name="page")
public class PageObject implements ComponentTypeObject{
    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    private String name;
    @XmlAttribute(name="id",required=true)
    private String id;

    @XmlElements({@XmlElement(name="tab", type=TabXmlAdapter.class)})
        private List<TabXmlAdapter> tabRef;`

Finally the controller for your MVC needs to return a model and view:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/get_page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView initPage()
{
    ModelAndView mav = null;
    try
    {
        PageObject myPage = (PageObject) Utilities.getUtilities().loadObjectFromFile(XmlComponentType.page);
        mav = new ModelAndView("page","page",myPage);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return mav;
}
```

Now while calling your URL ending with .json you'd get the JSON representation, and with .xml - and XML. Both are translated by the viewer, provided you gave the correct mapping when annotating the module.

Comment: Your solution works if spring-web or spring-mvc is used for dispatching. I am using RESTEasy. Thanks.

Comment: oh, didn't notice, was too rushed to answer :)